# VBA script that format celle with different color, slow spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm brand new to VBA and this is my first VBA script, it seems good enough, but it's made my spreadsheet really slow, I can do something to optimize it.

The script runs through some defined columns and checks for content "A" "S" and so on, and if the content matches, the script must color the cell a specific color and also the cell on the right

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim My_Range As Range
Set My_Range = Worksheets("Sæson").Range("J10:J40,Q10:Q39,X10:X40,AE10:AE39,AL10:AL40,AS10:AS40,AZ10:AZ39,BG10:BG40,BN10:BN39,BU10:BU40,CB10:CB40,CI10:CI38,CP10:CP40")
For Each cell In My_Range
   If cell.Value = "S" Then
      cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
   ElseIf cell.Value = "FE" Then
      cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
   ElseIf cell.Value = "SF" Then
      cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
   ElseIf cell.Value = "T" Then
      cell.Interior.Color = RGB(49, 255, 33)
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(49, 255, 33)
   ElseIf cell.Value = "TK" Then
      cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
   ElseIf cell.Value = "TH" Then
      cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 204)
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 204)
   ElseIf cell.Value = "SY" Then
      cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
   Else
      cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = xlNone
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Simple change would be to change the event from `Worksheet_SelectionChange` to `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: You should probably use `Intersect` to have this run only when a change is made in `MyRange`.

Comment: Is the data in `My_Range` values or formulas?

Comment: Marcucciboy2: that did not change anything. BigBen: that worked fine, but got a problem with Copy by click by right lower corner in a cell and then copy on cell to the lower cells. VBasic2008: My_Range data i values, and your solution is to hard for me. But the solution number two by SevC_10 solution "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" worked best for me, now it's running fast :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first option, you can also try to disable the `ScreenUpdating` option during the macro execution.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'variable declarations

    'disable screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '...
    'code
    '...

    're-enable screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Apply Criteria Colors

- It is assumed that the cells of the source range contain formulas. This will reapply colors to the whole range automatically (event-driven) each time the worksheet recalculates not necessarily meaning that a value in the range has changed (not quite efficient). It should be very fast on this small range though.
- If the cells contain values then you can manually run `applyCriteriaColors` to get the desired result. Also, a solution would then be a different code written for the `Worksheet_Change` event (you cannot use this one).
- Copy the codes to the appropriate modules.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub applyCriteriaColors()

    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    ' The number of columns to apply the color to.
    Const ColCount As Long = 2
    ' "cRangesList" has to contain a list of addresses of ONE-column ranges.
    Const cRangesList As String = "J10:J40,Q10:Q39,X10:X40,AE10:AE39," _
        & "AL10:AL40,AS10:AS40,AZ10:AZ39,BG10:BG40,BN10:BN39,BU10:BU40," _
        & "CB10:CB40,CI10:CI38,CP10:CP40"
    ' "CriteriaList" and "CellColors" have to have the same number of elements.
    ' Note that "Ranges" has the same number of elements (ranges) as well.
    Const CriteriaList As String = "S,FE,SF,T,TK,TH,SY"
    Dim CellColors As Variant: CellColors = VBA.Array( _
        16776960, 49407, 49407, 2228017, 15773696, 13408767, 255)
    
    ' Write values from Criteria List to Criteria Array.
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    ' Calculate Ranges Count (not to be confused with "aCount").
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(Criteria) + 1
    ' Define Ranges Array.
    Dim Ranges() As Range: ReDim Ranges(1 To rCount)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(cRangesList)
    ' Calculate Source Range Areas Count, the number of elements in Data Array.
    Dim aCount As Long: aCount = srg.Areas.Count
    ' Define Data Array (of Arrays).
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To aCount)
    ' Define One-Cell Array.
    Dim OneCell As Variant: ReDim OneCell(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        
    Dim arg As Range ' Source Range Current Area
    Dim cValue As Variant ' Current Value
    Dim cMatch As Variant ' Current Match
    Dim n As Long ' Source Range Areas Counter, Ranges Array Ranges Counter
    Dim i As Long ' Current Array (of Data Array) Rows Counter
    
    For n = 1 To aCount
        ' Write values from current area ('srg.Areas(n)') of Source Range
        ' ('srg') to current array ('Data(n)') of Data Array ('Data').
        Set arg = srg.Areas(n) '.Columns(1) ' ... ONE-column ranges
        If arg.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            Data(n) = arg.Value
        Else
            Data(n) = OneCell: Data(1, 1) = arg.Value
        End If
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data(n), 1)
            cValue = Data(n)(i, 1)
            If Not IsError(cValue) Then
                If Len(cValue) > 0 Then
                    ' Attempt to find a match in Criteria Array.
                    cMatch = Application.Match(cValue, Criteria, 0)
                    If IsNumeric(cMatch) Then
                        ' Combine matched cell resized by "ColCount"
                        ' with 'associated' range in Ranges Array.
                        If Ranges(cMatch) Is Nothing Then
                            Set Ranges(cMatch) _
                                = arg.Cells(i).Resize(, ColCount)
                        Else
                            Set Ranges(cMatch) = Union(Ranges(cMatch), _
                                arg.Cells(i).Resize(, ColCount))
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next n
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Reset colors. Note that "Resize" doesn't work with multi-area ranges.
    For n = 1 To aCount
        srg.Areas(n).Resize(, ColCount).Interior.Color = xlNone
    Next n
    ' Apply colors to the 'combined' ranges.
    For n = 1 To rCount
        If Not Ranges(n) Is Nothing Then
            Ranges(n).Interior.Color = CellColors(n - 1)
        End If
    Next n
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    applyCriteriaColors
End Sub
```